# Convert Date from text format to Custom format in Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I am having Dates in Text format in Excel in below format.
 Can you please suggest how to change it using Excel formula to a Custom format.

The format which I got for one of my report as:

```
20141214
20141215
20141216
20141217
20141218
20141219
20141220
20141221
20141222
20141223
```

and so on..

I need to convert it to format as **12-DEC-14** (i.e. DD-MMM-YY format).
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Please specify the platform/ language in the tag.

Comment: and also show some code what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your first date is in A1, use

`=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),LEFT(RIGHT(A1,4),2),RIGHT(A1,2))`

Once you have it as a date, right click on the cell and choose "Format Cell", then choose "Date", and pick your favorite Date format from the list that appears.

Comment: You can also directly display the **DD-MMM-YY** format using `TEXT`.